How to create operator= for custom struct?
I have a custom struct with a std::map<size_t, T> field:
template <typename T>
struct ProxyMap {
    auto begin() { return m.begin(); }
    auto end() { return m.end(); }
private:
    std::map<size_t, T> m;
};

int main () {
    ProxyMap<int> pm;
    pm[0] = -1;
    pm[3] = 23;
    pm[63] = 0;
    for (auto c : pm) {
        size_t a;
        int b;
        std::tie(a,b) = c;
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

What do I have to do for this example to compile?
What operator do I need, or maybe another function like convert to type?
I just reimplement begin() and end() methods.

Compiler should spot the undeclared method, as operator[]... Demo

You need to implement https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at, as suggested above.

Share the error message!  Learning how to read these error messages is a vital step to fixing them.  I strongly suspect that your real error message has nothing to do with a missing "operator =".

Your title is asking about operator=, but that operator is not what is missing in your code.  To make your code compile, you need to implement operator[] instead, and have it call the map::operator[], eg:
template <typename T>
struct ProxyMap {
    auto begin() { return m.begin(); }
    auto end() { return m.end(); }

    T& operator[](size_t key) { return m[key]; } // <-- HERE

private:
    std::map<size_t, T> m;
};

int main () {
    ProxyMap<int> pm;
    pm[0] = -1;
    pm[3] = 23;
    pm[63] = 0;
    for (auto c : pm) {
        size_t a;
        int b;
        std::tie(a,b) = c;
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Online demo
